# Friends one day and not the next day

Tags: conflict

My coworker constantly jokes and the other day she said to me, “hey hoochie get your work done”,  while I found this funny especially since I’m her superior, I threw a comment back “I would be done if you weren’t late”.  Well I think she took offense.  I asked her the next day if there was a problem, and she said “no” but, she has ignored me since, 4 days now.  It is immature and hurtful.  I don’t know how to address it or do I just leave it alone?

Comment: "while I found this funny especially since I’m her superior,"  Do you mean you are her supervisor?  If not, what does this mean?

Comment: @TheOnsen that's a standard term in a number of places for "person who is above you in the hierarchy (especially directly above)".

Comment: @Tilly maybe ask in "interpersonal skills" S.E. might be better suited.  Also, its difficult to know what is going through your coworkers head so any answer will be purely opinion based.

Comment: And I will say that you're correct -- it was extremely immature on YOUR part to respond as you did, and not immediately clean it up. You owe your report an apology.

Comment: If that type of banter is the norm, then the coworker should not get her nose out of joint - she made a sarcastic or funny comment and received one in return...